# Matching list of input values to database query in a Flask webapp

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Someone helped me write a script that will take URLs from one csv file, compare it to another, and output a return value based on the match.

new.csv --> 1 column: **urls**

scrapers.csv --> 2 columns: **scraper_dom**, **scraper_id**

That script looks like:

```
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from typing import List

def fnetloc(any) -> str:
    try:
        p = urlparse(any)
        return p.netloc
    except IndexError:
        return 'Error'

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, scraper_dom: str, scraper_id: str):
        self.scraper_dom = scraper_dom
        self.scraper_id = scraper_id
    def matches(self, fnetloc: str) -> bool:
        return fnetloc.endswith(self.scraper_dom)


class Site:
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.url = url
        self.fnetloc = fnetloc(url)
    def get_scraperid(self, scrapers: List[Scraper]) -> str:
        try:
            return next(x.scraper_id for x in scrapers if x.matches(self.fnetloc))
        except:
            return "[no scraper id found]"

sites = [Site(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(open("new.csv"))]
scrapers = [Scraper(row[0], row[1]) for row in csv.reader(open("scrapers.csv"))]

for site in sites:
    print(site.get_scraperid(scrapers), site.url, sep="\t")
```

This works great, but I'm working on putting this into a webapp, and am trying to work out the same logic utilizing PythonAnywhere's MySql database and SQLAlchemy.
Here's what I've got so far (besides the HTML templates the views render):

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret_key"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = db.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/username$scrapers?charset=utf8mb4".format(
    username="username",
    password="password",
    hostname="username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    databasename="username$scrapers",
))
app.config[SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI]  = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db.Model = declarative_base()

class Scrapers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Scrapers"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    scraper_dom = db.Column(db.String(255))
    scraper_id = db.Column(db.String(128))

db.Model.metadata.create_all(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

Session = db.sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
session = Session()

scrapers = session.query(Scrapers.scraper_dom, Scrapers.scraper_id)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "Get":
        return render_template("url_page.html")
    else:
        return render_template("url_page.html")

@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit():
    que = [urlparse(item).netloc for item in request.form["urls"].split('\n')]
    ids = scrapers.filter(Scrapers.scraper_dom.in_(que))
    results = (ids, '\t', request.form["urls"])
    return render_template("submit.html", results=results)
```

The trouble I'm having is in this bit:

```
@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit():
    que = [urlparse(item).netloc for item in request.form["urls"].split('\n')]
    ids = scrapers.filter(Scrapers.scraper_dom.in_(que))
    results = (ids, '\t', request.form["urls"])
    return render_template("submit.html", results=results)
```

I need `que` to iterate through my multiline input (users will be pasting large lists of urls from excel), which it does great. I then need to take each `.netloc` value and compare it to **scraper_dom** to return the corresponding **scraper_id** value. Finally, outputting the original url and scraper_id value in columns, similar to this (though I don't need column names in the output):

[image: output_example]

Problem is, as it's written, it is just returning the SQL from the line:

`ids = scrapers.filter(Scrapers.scraper_dom.in_(que))`

Something like (Given an input of www.1688.com):

[image: broken_output]

What am I missing? I've tried writing `ids` a few different ways and I get errors:

`ids = scrapers.filter(scrapers.scraper_dom.in_(que))`

Error:

*AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'scraper_dom'*

`ids = Scrapers.query.filter(Scrapers.scraper_dom.in_((que)))`

Error:

*AttributeError: type object 'Scrapers' has no attribute 'query'*

I'm using the idea of matching based off of:
`[x for x in a if x in b]`

Comment: What you see is the `str()` representation of the `Query`. You have to either iterate over it (which executes it), or call `Query.all()` to execute it and fetch the results as a list. "AttributeError: type object 'Scrapers' has no attribute 'query'" hints that you've another non-model  class with the same name.

Comment: @Ilja Everila in my first script I noticed what you mentioned being used in the ```print``` line. 

Something like ```for i in ids:  results = (i, '\t', request.form["urls"])```?

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I'm now getting *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment* looking into that error, it seems a scoping issue with ```results```. I have tried passing results as a parameter to ```def submit()``` but run into issues with positional arguments... How can I pass the iteration of ```ids``` to ```results``` without encountering these variable reference errors?

Comment: Not quite like that, that'll just reassign `results` one by one to each result of the query, until finally `results` holds the last and only the last result. ...Except when there are no results, in which case `results` is never assigned to, and hence the `UnboundLocalError`. If all you need is *all* the results, use `scrapers.filter(...).all()` to obtain the list.

Comment: Gotcha. I had seen `.all()` in the docs but I had put it at the end of my query string `scrapers` and tried the iteration in the submit view. Thank you for helping!